# Checking a HTML string for unopened tags

Tags: c#, .net, html-parsing

I have a string as a HTML source and I want to check whether the HTML source which is string contains a tag which is not opened.

For example the string below contains `</u>` after WAVEFORM which has no opening `<u>`.

```
WAVEFORM</u> YES, <u>NEGATIVE AUSCULTATION OF EPIGASTRUM</u> YES,
```

I just want to check for these types of unopened tag and then I have to append the open tag to the start of the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this specific case you can use [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to assert if the HTML is well formed or if you have tags not opened.

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

htmlDoc.LoadHtml(
    "WAVEFORM</u> YES, <u>NEGATIVE AUSCULTATION OF EPIGASTRUM</u> YES,");

foreach (var error in htmlDoc.ParseErrors)
{
    // Prints: TagNotOpened
    Console.WriteLine(error.Code);
    // Prints: Start tag <u> was not found
    Console.WriteLine(error.Reason); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy. You can't directly use an HTML parser as it's not valid HTML, but you can't easily throw a regex at the whole thing as regexes can't cope with nesting or other HTML complications.

Probably about the best you could do would be to use a regex to find each markup structure, eg. something like:

```
<(\w+)(?:\s+[-\w]+(?:\s*(?:=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">\s][^>\s]*)))?)*\s*>
|</(\w+)\s*>
|<!--.*?-->
```

Start with an empty tags-to-open list and an empty tags-to-close list. For each match in the string, look at groups 1 and 2 to see if you've got a start or end tag. (Or a comment, which you can ignore.)

If you've got a start tag, you need to know if it needs closing, ie. if it's one of the `EMPTY` content-model tags like `<img>`. If a element is `EMPTY`, it doesn't need closing so you can ignore it. (If you have XHTML, this is all a bit easier.)

If you have a start-tag, add the tag name in the regex group to the tags-to-close list. If you've got an end tag, take one tag off the end of the tags-to-close list (it should be the same tag name as was on there, otherwise you've got invalid markup. If there are no tags on the tags-to-close list, instead add the tag name to the tags-to-open list.

Once you've got to the end of the input string, prepend each of the tags-to-open tags to the string in reverse order, and append the close tags for the the tags-to-close to the end, again in reverse order.

(Yeah, I'm parsing HTML with regex. I think the nastiness of this demonstrates why you don't want to. If there's anything you can do to avoid having already snipped your markup in the middle of a tag, do that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    using HtmlDocument = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument;
```

/* This function is useful for finding errors in BBCode or HTML.
Typical error is "End tag  not found line:1, char:592"
and notepad can be used to easily locate any errors.  I had to
append a space after the strIn as a trailing < was not found.*/

```
    public static string HttpParse(string strIn)
    {
        string strRtn = "";
        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(strIn + " ");
        foreach(var strErr in htmlDoc.ParseErrors)
        {
            strRtn += strErr.Reason + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return strRtn;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**