# Validating HTML Tags in a String in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Assume that we have the following HTML strings.

```
string A = " <table width=325><tr><td width=325>test</td></tr></table>"
string B = " <<table width=325><tr><td width=325>test</td></table>"
```

How can we validate *A* or *B* in C# according to HTML specifications?

A should return **true** whereas B should return **false**.

Comment: You could parse the string and add up all of the < and > characters. If either of them is an odd amount you could assume it's invalid (for this case)

Comment: I think both of the html you have provided completely incorrect according to spec.

Comment: There is a number of HTML tags in HTML4 and HTML5 that do not require the use of a closing tag for valid HTML: optgroup, option, p, tbody, td, tr, tfoot, thead, th

Comment: I fixed the </tr> on string A.

Comment: Yes as @alex said, counting < and > does not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://web.archive.org/web/20110820163031/http://markbeaton.com/SoftwareInfo.aspx?ID=81a0ecd0-c41c-48da-8a39-f10c8aa3f931

Github link: https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged

This guy has written a .NET wrapper for HTMLTidy. I haven't used it but it may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 14):

For this specific case you can use [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to assert if the HTML is well formed or if you have tags not opened.

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

htmlDoc.LoadHtml(
    "WAVEFORM</u> YES, <u>NEGATIVE AUSCULTATION OF EPIGASTRUM</u> YES,");

foreach (var error in htmlDoc.ParseErrors)
{
    // Prints: TagNotOpened
    Console.WriteLine(error.Code);
    // Prints: Start tag <u> was not found
    Console.WriteLine(error.Reason); 
}
```

[Checking a HTML string for unopened tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164424/checking-a-html-string-for-unopened-tags/3164945#3164945)

Comment: +1 for using an existing library instead of trying to hack it together yourself.

Comment: just a warning, whilst the above example works, this: "<p>example<p>" doesnt trigger any parser errors.

Comment: This also does not throw any parser errors: <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/clipboard.min.js" <="" script="">

Comment: @AndrewBullock That is because it indeed is valid HTML.

Comment: @JeremeGuenther Can you link to the github bug ticket that you surely created when you stumbled over this issue?

Comment: No bug ticket, wasn't sure if that was really a bug since it is javascript, not html.  The agility pack seems to have limited js support.

Answer (score 2):

One point to start with is checking if it's valid XML.

by the way, I think both your examples are incorrect as you've left out the `</tr>` from both.

Comment: HTML is not valid XML, XHTML is.

Comment: @alex, that's true but at least it could be a start as all other checks would be really hard

Comment: There is a number of HTML tags in HTML4 and HTML5 that do not require the use of a closing tag for valid HTML: optgroup, option, p, tbody, td, tr, tfoot, thead, th

Comment: @thekip As long as there is one single HTML element with no closing tag, the entire XML-validity check would be pointless. And there's a pretty good chance there is one.

Comment: XML is much more strict than HTML and XMLReader does not give proper results.